# Android studio gradle won't build error AAPT2 straight after install

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I downloaded AndroidStudio on my laptop and the only SPECIAL thing that I did was that I changed default install location because the defualt hdd was almost full. So than I open AndroidStudio and the default "hello world" won't build and i get error AAPT2.
please help

Comment: can you please show error log?
try adding the following line in gradle.properties
android.enableAapt2=false

Comment: Do not disable aapt2! aapt1 will be fully deprecated very soon so this is NOT a fix. What you want is to find the reason why it fails. Which version of android studio did you download? Are you on Windows? Can you go to the Terminal tab and run "gradlew assembleDebug" and post the output here (modify the question post)?